# Mysql team/score

Tags: php, mysql

I want to create an query to have the all matchs that a player win.

So, I have this table

```
ID_PLAYER1       ID_PLAYER2      SCORE_PLAYER1       SCORE_PLAYER2
   1                4                5                    3
   2                1                3                    4
   3                4                2                    0
```

I want to have this :

```
ID_PLAYER     MATCH_WIN
1                 2
2                 0
3                 1
4                 0
```

Thank you !

Comment: Can you post what you've got so far? It's always best to post your previous attempts even if they failed. It gives people a place to start in helping answer your question.

Comment: SELECT score_player1, score_player2
FROM matchs ON id = id_player1 OR id = id_player2
GROUP BY id

I tried this but it's not worked...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm answering this because it's non-trivial and because I want to see if I can actually do it :p

```
SELECT `ID_PLAYER`, COUNT(*) AS `MATCH_WIN` FROM
    (SELECT
        IF(`SCORE_PLAYER1`>`SCORE_PLAYER2`, `ID_PLAYER1`, `ID_PLAYER2`) AS `ID_PLAYER`
        FROM `your_table_name_here`
    ) AS `tmp`
GROUP BY `ID_PLAYER`
```

Comment: I tried but it's not worked for me. Can you give me a sqlfiddle ? @niet thank you

Comment: Forgot the group by. Try it now?